# Create File object without saving

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, discord.js

I'm trying to look for a way to create a `.txt` File object without saving it to disk in `Node.js`. In browser I'd do something like

```js
new File(['file_contents'], 'file_name.txt', {type: 'text/plain'})
```

The end aim is to create a `.txt` file object temporarily for my Discord Bot to send as a message attachment.

From the `discord.js` documentation, I presume I'm supposed to create a `Buffer` or `Stream` object representing the file.

I'm already using `require('node-fetch')` library to read attachments in messages, if that has any relevancy (but can't see anything in their docs on this either).

Comment: No luck with googling/searching here --- all solutions involve reading existing files/making them just to save to disc. A link to example/doc on how to do it would be appreciated. It would be preferred to use a way without needing more libraries (eg. just writing Buffer literal representing text file), but I understand if such a solution is too complex.

Comment: I have added an answer that relates to saving a file to the disk, once you are done sending it, you can always delete the file afterwards. May I ask why you don't want to save it to the disk?

Comment: Because I assume it's not necessary - it isn't with the File Web API? I'm under the assumption writing to disk and then having to clean up after is less efficient than just creating the object and then discarding it.

Comment: in Typescript, you can make a File object without saving the file in a local folder.
new File([JSON.stringify(''content)], 'metadata.json')

Comment: dush, that sounds amazing - but where are you importing a File type from? It's not inbuilt to ts-node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After playing around in console I've found `Buffer.from('string of txt file contents')` to represent the file seems to work fine.

Usage:

```js
channel.send(new Discord.MessageAttachment(Buffer.from('Hello World'), 'file_name.txt'))
```

Comment: Please let me know if there are downsides to this as I'm not familiar with using Buffers --- it appears to work fine at surface level to me.

Answer (score -2):

In order to write a text file in JS you should use the `fs` library, included in Node.js.

Here is an example of writing to a file:

```js
fs = require('fs');

let content = "Hello world!";

fs.writeFile('file.txt', content, function (err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    // Code here will execute if successfully written
});
```

Then in order to send a local file to Discord you can use `.send` with an object containing a `files` property in it, like this:

```js
channel.send({
    files: [{
        attachment: 'entire/path/to/file.txt',
        name: 'file.txt'
    }]
}).then(() => {
    // Delete file
    fs.unlink('file.txt');
});
```

You can see more about `.send()` [here](https://discord.js.org/?source=post_page---------------------------#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send) and you can find more about the `fs` module [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)